# How to get rebar to run 'make' for a dependency?

Tags: erlang, rebar

One of my dependencies doesn't use `rebar` -- it uses a Makefile. How do I get `rebar` to run this Makefile, rather than attempting to compile the source itself?

Note that I'd like to continue using rebar for everything else.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [rebar.config example file](https://github.com/basho/rebar/blob/develop/rebar.config.sample), you could mark the dependency as `raw`, meaning it's not compiled by rebar.  Then you could add either a pre or post compile hook to run make in that dependency directory.  The rebar `generate` command should still be able to pick up any Erlang apps built there, assuming they have OTP file structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `rebar` through `make`, you can add this kind of code to your Makefile:

```
    @if [[ -f $@/Makefile ]]; \
    then echo 'make -C $@ all' ; \
               make -C $@ all  ; \
    else echo 'cd $@ && rebar get-deps compile && cd ../..' ; \
               cd $@ && rebar get-deps compile && cd ../..  ; fi
```

It checks if `$@` has a Makefile then decides whether to use `make` or `rebar`.

This snippet is from `erl.mk` https://github.com/fenollp/erl-mk/blob/master/erl.mk#L17-L21